# Do unit quaternions admit a continuous square root function?

Tags: solution-verification, homotopy-theory, radicals, topological-groups, quaternions

Let $G$ be a multiplicative group. A function $\text{sqrt}: G \to G$ is a **square root function** iff, for every $x \in G$, $(\text{sqrt}(x))^2 = x$.

The unit real numbers, namely $\pm 1$, doesn't even have a well-defined square root function. The unit complex numbers $S^1 \subset \mathbb{C}$ has a well-defined square root function, but no branch cut is continuous. But what about the unit quaternions $S^3 \subset \mathbb{H}$?

I think the answer is negative. Here's my attempt. Suppose a continuous $\text{sqrt}: S^3 \to S^3$ exists. Since $S^3$ is a topological group (and thus an H-space), the homotopy set $[S^3, S^3]$ has a group structure (denoted by $+$), defined as pointwise multiplication. Now consider the homotopy class $[\text{sqrt}]$. By the definition of $\text{sqrt}$, and by the group structure of $[S^3, S^3]$, $[\text{sqrt}] + [\text{sqrt}] = [(\cdot)^2 \circ \text{sqrt}] = [\text{id}]$. This contradicts against that $[\text{id}]$ is a generator of the infinite cyclic group $[S^3, S^3] = \mathbb{Z}$.

By a similar proof, the unit octonions $S^7 \subset \mathbb{O}$ doesn't admit a continuous square root function either. Is my proof correct?

Comment: Looks reasonable to me. One question: There are two group structures on $\pi_3(S^3)$, one  induced by the quaternion structure, and the other induced by the group structure of homotopy groups. Do you see why they are the same thing?

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer It's covered in Arkowitz.

Comment: Ok. :) incidentally, your proof in fact works for any Lie group. The 'class' in $[S^3,S^3]$ is a special case of the so-called degree of a map of orientable manifolds. One way to compute degrees is to count pre-images at generic points. You can use this to show that the squaring operation has degree $2^r$, where $r$ is the rank of your Lie group. (Specifically, take the generic point on your maximal torus, where it's easy to count pre-images.) Now, if $\operatorname{sqrt}$ existed, then $\deg(\operatorname{sqrt}^2) = 2^r \cdot \deg \operatorname{sqrt} = 1$, which is impossible.